# Compressing a file using Huffman coding when the characters all have similar repetitions?

Tags: java, huffman-code

So i have been implementing huffman compression on a bunch of different types of files (.jpg, .txt, .docx) and I've noticed a lot that sometimes the compressed file is sometimes almost the same as the original file (ex: 251,339kb -> 250,917kb(without header!)) I'm pretty sure my code is solid, though i'm not sure if this is right or not. The thing that i've noticed is that the character frequencies are very similar, so for example I'll have 10 characters that all have for example 65 repetitions and then another 10 characters that have 66 repetitions, and then another 10 characters that have 67 repetitions, etc etc. And because the files are big, the compressed character representation code end up having the same size as the original, or even larger (9 bits). Is this a normal thing when compressing using huffman?

Comment: It is normal that data which is already pretty random doesn't get smaller but could get larger. What do you expect to happen when you try to compress an already compressed file?

Comment: @PeterLawrey's answer is spot on. Additional things to think about-if you have an uncompressed image file like an uncomp. TIFF, the frequency of using 0 to 255 in each byte will tend to become evenly distributed. The exception being an image that is mostly in a single color family. For instance, something that is mostly bright blue.  For text files, it takes 7 bits to represent English (A-Z,a-z,0-9, plus punctuation and symbols). For normal text, Huffman will do reasonably well because English tends to favor certain characters more than others.

Comment: An example, say you have lots of clothes and you put them in a vaccum bag, you suck all the air out of it and it gets small.  Now put this in another vaccum bag, does it get smaller then second time, possibly if the first bag wasn't very good, but it's more likely to just make it larger.

Answer (score 1):

When encoding with Huffman, divide your file in to smaller chunks under the covers. The idea is that smaller chunks will have more bias than a giant file that averages everything. For example, one chunk may have lots of 0x00s in it. Another chunk may have 0xFF and so on. Then compressing each chunk with the Huffman algorithm will pick up those biases to its advantage.  Of course if the chunks are too small then the Huffman code table will be a larger fraction of the compressed chunk and you lose the chunking benefits. In the Deflate case, code tables are in the order of 50-100 bytes.

Of course as the other respondents commented if your source files are already compressed (JPEG etc) you are not going to find any biases or redundancies however you chunk it.